# Elastic Search geohashes return full details not just doc_count

Tags: json, geolocation, elasticsearch, geohashing

I am working on a property aggrigation website that would store hundred of thosuands of properties. To map areas I am using Elastic Search's GEO Hashing to reduce the number of matches returned for a given zoom level.

The code to generate the hashes is as follows:

```
`GET _search
 {
"from": 0,
"size": 0,
"query": {
    "match_all": {}
},
"filter": {
    "and": [{
        "range": {
            "property.price": {
                "lte": 1000000000
            }
        }
    }, {
        "geo_bounding_box": {
            "property.location": {
                "top_left": {
                    "lat": 42.88679,
                    "lon": -73.5081419
                },
                "bottom_right": {
                    "lat": 41.2390897,
                    "lon": -69.9279921
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        "term": {
            "property.rental": false
        }
    }, {
        "term": {
            "property.country": "US"
        }
    }]
},
"sort": [{
    "property.price": "asc"
}],
"facets": {
    "stat1": {
        "statistical": {
            "field": "price"
        }
    }
},
"aggs": {
    "geohash": {
        "filter": {
            "geo_bounding_box": {
                "property.location": {
                    "top_left": {
                        "lat": 42.88679,
                        "lon": -73.5081419
                    },
                    "bottom_right": {
                        "lat": 41.2390897,
                        "lon": -69.9279921
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "aggregations": {
            "locations": {
                "geohash_grid": {
                    "field": "location",
                    "precision": 8
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}`

The resulting JSON comes back with the number of matches per GeoHash and is working, except that there doesnt seem to be any way to include the property details in the result, or include an ID to get back to it when clicked?

The result is as follows:

```
`{
   "took": 94,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
   "total": 13,
   "max_score": 0,
   "hits": []
},
   "facets": {
   "stat1": {
     "_type": "statistical",
     "count": 50,
     "total": 90640800,
     "min": 1,
     "max": 19500000,
     "mean": 1812816,
     "sum_of_squares": 628677324820002,
     "variance": 9287244646544.04,
     "std_deviation": 3047498.0962330457
  }
   },
   "aggregations": {
   "geohash": {
         "doc_count": 16,
         "locations": {
            "buckets": [
           {
              "key": "drt05n43",
              "doc_count": 2
           },
           {
              "key": "drt0v0q8",
              "doc_count": 1
           },
           {
              "key": "drt0sr3e",
              "doc_count": 1
           },
           {
              "key": "drt0kgr8",
              "doc_count": 1
           },
           {
              "key": "drt07sdk",
              "doc_count": 1
           },
           {
              "key": "drt075vd",
              "doc_count": 1
           },
           {
              "key": "drt05n19",
              "doc_count": 1
           },
           {
              "key": "drt05jgv",
              "doc_count": 1
           },
           {
              "key": "drsbrgvh",
              "doc_count": 1
           },
           {
              "key": "drmpgznd",
              "doc_count": 1
           },
           {
              "key": "drmpft6c",
              "doc_count": 1
           },
           {
              "key": "drmpe6bg",
              "doc_count": 1
           },
           {
              "key": "drmp7ybz",
              "doc_count": 1
           },
           {
              "key": "drmgkj77",
              "doc_count": 1
           },
           {
              "key": "drkzzj3d",
              "doc_count": 1
           }
        ]
     }
  }
```

}
}`

Any help in adding additional property data to the result would be HUGELY appreciated.

Thanks :)

p.s. sorry about the code intendation, SO's code detection with JSON is a little weird.

Comment: Iam also stuck at this level. Can we have the document_ids / record_ids in each bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use nested aggregations:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-aggregation.html

Using elastic.js from http://www.fullscale.co/elasticjs/

```
ejs.GeoHashGridAggregation('Geohash-Grid')
            .field('Geohash')
            .precision(precision)
            .aggregation(
                ejs.TermsAggregation('HouseType').field('HouseType')
            )
            .aggregation(
                ejs.TermsAggregation('HouseColor').field('HouseColor')
            )
        );
```

But that is just one example. The output will then have nested aggregation counts for documents that match each geohash.